# 2 consecutive digits using RegEx?

Tags: regular-expression

Is there a way to print words containing 2 consecutive digits divided with whitespace?

Regardless of the input, is that possible? If yes, please share your ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use only `digit` class:

```
grep -o '[^[:digit:]][[:digit:]] [[:digit:]][^[:digit:]]'
```

This assumes that `a1 23b` should not be matched, because it is 3 consecutive (not counting a space) digits.

Answer (score 0):

If something contains a whitespace it is usually not considered a "word" any more.

```
> echo "foo fu1 2bar baz" | grep -oE '[[:alpha:]]+[0-9] [0-9][[:alpha:]]+'
fu1 2bar
```